# Transformers in type signature or not?

Tags: api, haskell, monad-transformers

Just thinking about an API design. What is "common" in Haskell? Transformers in type signature or rather "hidden"?

```hs
findById :: ID -> IO (Maybe User)
findById x = runMaybeT $ do
  ...
  return User
```

or

```hs
findById :: ID -> MaybeT IO User
findById x = do
  ...
  return User
```

Comment: A third alternative to consider: one of `(MonadIO m, Alternative m) => ID -> m User` if there's really no interesting error information you can report, or `(MonadIO m, MonadError MyFancyError m) => ID -> m User` if there is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is for something simple, and it's only a few functions that do this maybe-in-IO, I would just make the type `IO (Maybe User)`.

If this is a pattern that stretches across your library, I would give a semi-abstract name to the tfm-stack monad:

```
type Request = MaybeT IO

findById :: ID -> Request User
```

... or even

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
newtype Request a = Request (runRequest :: MaybeT IO a)
   deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)
```

Making the signature `ID -> MaybeT IO User` isn't very good: the transformer only helps if you're doing a whole bunch of actions in that monad, but in that case always writing out `MaybeT IO` violates the DRY principle.

Comment: for the sake of interest, `findById` would then look like
`findById :: ID -> Request User \n findById 1 = return User \n findById _ = Request . MaybeT $ return Nothing`
Right?

Comment: Yeah. If you also derive [`Alternative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative) then you can simplify the failure case to `findById _ = empty`.